# Piping \write18 commands and ltxguide

Tags: input, shell-escape

The following works in an `article`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\title{Foo}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\input{|"echo foo bar | grep foo"}
\end{document}
```

Instead of that `\input`, this also works:

```
\immediate\write18{echo foo bar | grep foo > /tmp/test.txt}
\input{/tmp/test.txt}
\immediate\write18{rm /tmp/test.txt}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with the `ltxguide` class (neither option). The second, with `\write18`, works when not piping (i.e. just `echo foo bar > /tmp/test.txt`), the first doesn't work at all, also without piping.

How  can I use pipes together with the `ltxguide` class?

The error I get with `\input{|"echo foo bar | grep foo"}` and `ltxguide`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.17 \input{|"echo foo bar | grep foo"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ltxguide` class has

```
% Make |...| a synonym for \verb|...|.
\RequirePackage{shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb{\|}
```

Just add in your document preamble

```
\DeleteShortVerb{\|}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I want to do this in a package. Would it be bad practice to add `\DeleteShortVerb{\|}` to that package?

Comment: @CamilStaps Not at all; just make the users aware that they can't use `|foo|` as shorthand for `\verb|foo|`